# Клиент сервер TCP

Tags: c, unix, gcc, tcp

Делаю сетевую консольную игрушку для курсача, если подключатся через 127.0.0.1 или через локальный ip то все работает, но когда пытаюсь связать клиент сервер через ip инета(типа 84.242.206.234) то клиент не подключается, чяднт?
Сервер:

```
    int sock, n, port = def_port;
    int;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    printf("Порт: %d ожидаю подключения\n", ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));
    listen(sock, 0);
    int tmp = sock;
    sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);
```

Клиент:

```
int sock, n, port = def_port;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

char ip[100];
printf("Введите ip адрес: ");
scanf("%s", ip);

bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

if(inet_aton(ip, &servaddr.sin_addr) == 0){
        printf("Неправильный ip адрес\n");
    return;
}

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0){
        printf("Не удалось подключиться\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Как вы подключены к интернету?

Comment: Дополнительно в файрволл на компьютере должно быть правило, разрешающее входящие соединения на соответствующий порт...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось проще, надо было открыть порт на роутере

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего твоя проблема, в том что запускаешь не с сервера. А через домашний компьютер, который работает через роутер.

Суть в том, что для домашнего ПК провайдер выдает динамически ip адреса внутри сети. А тебе для полноценного сервера нужен статический адрес. Либо пробрасывать порт (провайдер не разрешит, заставит купить статический ip).

Совет использовать VPS, или любой VPN(например, хамачи).